# rsync throws error when using priv/pub key

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, freenas, public-key

I have a .sh file that I can manually trigger to run a backup to a remote server on the local network. It looks like this:

```
rsync -avzP -e ssh -i /mnt/local/ root@192.168.9.114:/DataVolume/shares/NASBackup
```

This requires authorization, which is why I created a public key, that I stored in /mnt/local/.backup/authorized_keys.pub

I then created a new .sh script that contains the following

```
rsync -avzP 'ssh -i /mnt/local/.backup/authorized_keys -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /mnt/local 192.168.9.114:/DataVolume/shares/NASBackup
```

It throws a permission denied error. Specifically the following:

```
rsync: change_dir "/mnt/local/.backup//ssh -i /mnt/local/.backup" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1053) [sender=3.0.9]
./backup-start-new.sh: /mnt/local: Permission denied
```

The reason for the location of the .pub key on the local machine I attempt to run rsync from is due to that my authorized keys folder is unwriteable, so I placed my keys elsewhere. On the remote server, the .pub key is placed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

The main problem in the error is the permission denied on the /mnt/local folder that I cant figure out. The originating server is a FreeNAS server.

Comment: You forgot `-e`.

Comment: I added -e for it to look like this: rsync -avzP -e 'ssh -i /mnt/local/.backup/authorized_keys -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /mnt/local 192.168.9.114:/DataVolume/shares/NASBackup and now it throws the following error: Use "rsync --daemon --help" to see the daemon-mode command-line options.
Please see the rsync(1) and rsyncd.conf(5) man pages for full documentation.
See http://rsync.samba.org/ for updates, bug reports, and answers
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1504) [Receiver=3.0.9]
./backup-start-new.sh: /mnt/local: Permission denied

Comment: You need to use your _private_ file for connecting. (-i ...) or simply copy it to `~/.ssh`. And check if you have permission for `/mnt/local/`

Comment: I dont understand? Use  my private file for connecting? The permissions to /mnt/local is where I am getting confused, as I am not sure why the rsync .sh script when running WITH the public key argument is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` permissions set to `0600` and `~/.ssh` to `0700`?

SSH is very picky with permissions on the files.

Comment: On local server or on remote server?

Comment: On remote, authorized keys must contain the public key form your local machine.

Comment: Just to clarify, you must generate a SSH key pair on your local machine, then insert the public key on the remote server ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, those directories must have the permissions set as I told you before.

Also, it is tricky when you copy/paste depending on the terminal you are using, since public keys must be only one line and they tend to be pasted as several. Take care of this.

Comment: Yes, but my error starts before it even connects. It is a local machine permission settings that prevents me from even getting to the remote machine. I for some reason do not via rsync have permission to /mnt/local to run it

Comment: The public key on the remote server is one line, and I copied it into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, after generating it on my local machine. I used this tutorial for generating: http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html

Comment: Run a `ssh -v` and paste the output.

If you can passwordless SSH into the machine, there is other problem here.

Comment: You can also check that the user you are connecting with to the remote machine really has permission to write on /mnt/local, this could be the problem too.

Comment: Isnt rsync first running locally, and then connecting to the remote machine to the path specified? /mnt/local is my local machine folder that I want to backup to 192.168.9.114:/DataVolume/shares/NASBackup

Comment: Welcome to Super User. In general you shouldn't ask questions in the "answer" field. Asking for clarification belongs to the comments ([gain 50 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174) to be able to comment). On the other hand setting the right permissions may be (I guess) a solution to some similar problems, if not this particular one, so your answer may be useful for future users.